# PHP mysql COUNT not returning instead of 0

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am trying to check if a name exists. Query should return 0 because the field is empty but returning 1 instead. help.

```
function profile_exists($user) { //checks that profile exists
    $profile_ex = mysql_query(
        "SELECT COUNT(profile_name) FROM user_info WHERE id = '{$user}'");

    if(!confirm_query($profile_ex)) {
        return false;   
    } else {
        if (mysql_result($profile_ex, 0) == 1) {
            echo mysql_result($profile_ex, 0);
            exit;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `mysqli_` or `PDO` with prepared statements to prevent against SQL injection.

It will always return 1 because you are using an aggregate function (`COUNT`). Select a column from your table instead:

```
SELECT profile_name FROM ...
```

However, if you are only interested in checking whether the profile exists, use `mysqli_num_rows`. If you wish to check whether the profile exists and return data, use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Answer (score 2):

You have one row instead of 0 rows because `COUNT(*)` returns one row of data, the count which has the value of 0 in this case.

You will need to run the query and then check the value of count.

Example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM ...");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if( $row['count'] == 0){
    return False;
}else{
    return True;
}
```

Comment: "What if `count` is > 1"; Then something really really bad had happened and False should be returned; look at the query in the question `WHERE id = '{$user}'` - this makes the assumption that id is a auto-incrementing prime key which is/should always be unique.

Comment: That's a pretty large assumption (`id` is a PK with `AUTO_INCREMENT`). Basically you're saying that the user doesn't exist if they have more than 1 profile.

Comment: Basically, I'm answering their question of why they have a result set of one row instead of zero rows.  The table structure is irrelevant to that ends, and without the table schema I made an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks abit complex, try this instead:

```
$profile_ex = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE id = '$user'");
$profile_ex = mysql_num_rows($profile_ex);

if ( $profile_ex > 0 ) {
echo "exists"; } else {
echo "doesn't exist";
}
```

Hope this helps